# How to implement one-to-many boolean relationships in a GUI, using core data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsarray

I have a number of persons in a core data model, and a number of skills. I'd like to have a window where the user can add or remove skills. This window also has a table of persons, with an `NSCheckBox` next to it. The check box indicates if this person has the skill. The persons are in an array controller called PersonsList. The skills are in an array controller called Skills.
Can I bind things so that every "personName" in PersonsList has a list of "capable" booleans that relate to the Skills? The person has a many-to-many relationship to the skills.

One person can have more skills, and one skill can be had by more persons.

I hope someone well-versed in Core Data can help me out here. I'm hoping it can be done without some `NSArray` holding the booleans.

Comment: The person would probably have NSMutableSet property called skills that references all their skills. Then you add or remove skills from it

Comment: Are you sure that only one person can have the same skill? People and skills sound like a many-to-many situation to me.

Comment: :). I meant that every person can have multiple skills. So you are right, it's in fact many to many!

Comment: I would have to do the NSMutableSet programmatically, right? I.e. no property or relation type that can/should do this for me?

Comment: Relations between entities in CoreData are NSSets but I think you would have to tie them to the GUI yourself because it isn't always so clear how to represent a *-to-many relationship (I.e. probably no built in way).